# Side menu popout with z-index not showing above bootstrap 5 card without z-index

Tags: css, css-position, bootstrap-5, z-index, card

On small devices I’d like when the user clicks the icon the menu is popped out. However, the menu is hiding behind the card. The only way I was able to get it to show above was by adding z-index: -1 to the card but that will not allow me to click anything on the card

**Snippet of the menu with the popout**

```
<li class="m-item sidebar-dropdown”>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <span class="material-symbols-rounded icon">
                        monetization_on
                    </span>
                    <span>Money</span>
                </a>
                <div class="submenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="section-title">Balance</li>
                        <li><a>Step 1</a></li>
                        <li><a>Step 2</a></li>
                        <li><a>Step 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="section-title">Penalties</li>
                        <li><a)">Penalties</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
```

**This is the CSS for the sidebar**

```
@import '../abstract/_mixins.scss';

.sidebar {
    width: 68px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 66px;
    height: calc(100% - 72px);
    background-color: $white;
    border-right: 2px solid $grey-3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .menuitems {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;

        .m-item {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            @include body-16-medium;
            padding: 10px 5px;

            .icon {
                margin-right: 10px;
                color: $grey-4;
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }

            .img-icon {
                width: 22px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                filter: invert(52%) sepia(1%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(93%) contrast(88%);
            }

            a {
                display: inline-flex;


                span {
                    &:last-of-type {
                        color: $grey-4;
                        display: none;
                    }
                }
            }

            &.active {
                background-color: $grey-8;
                border-radius: 6px;

                .icon {
                    color: $blue-4;
                }

                a {
                    span {
                        @include body-16-semi;
                        color: $blue-4;
                    }
                }
            }

            &.sidebar-dropdown {
                a {
                    position: relative;

                    &:after {
                        content: "\e5cc";
                        position: absolute;
                        font-family: $font-materials;
                        right: 0px;
                        font-size: 1.25rem;
                        font-weight: 800;
                    }
                }

                .submenu {
                    margin-top: 12px;
                    display: none;

                    ul {
                        list-style: none;

                        li {
                            &.section-title {
                                margin-bottom: 12px;
                                @include body-16-semi;
                            }

                            a {
                                @include body-14-medium;
                                margin-bottom: 12px;
                                color: $grey-4;

                                &:after {
                                    content: "";
                                }

                                &.active {
                                    color: $black;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                &.submenu-open {
                    a {
                        &:after {
                            transform: rotate(90deg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@media(max-width:480px) {
    .sidebar {
        left: -100%;
    }
}

@media(min-width:480px) and (max-width:768px) {
    .sidebar-dropdown {
        position: relative;

        a {
            &:after {
                content: "" !important;
            }
        }

        .submenu {
            z-index: 1001;
            background-color: $grey-8;
            position: absolute;
            left: 52px;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            display: none;
            box-shadow: 0rem 0rem 2.5rem 0rem rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.1);

            ul {
                li {
                    a {
                        color: $white !important;
                        font-weight: 400 !important;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .sidebar {
        .menuitems {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
    }
}


@media (min-width:768px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 260px;

        .menuitems {
            .m-item {
                a {
                    span {
                        &:last-of-type {
                            display: block;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

**This is my card. The only CSS that is applied to the card other than the bootstrap styling is just a border radius**

```
 <div class="card container-card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <a asp-controller="Dashboard" asp-action=“GetStarted” class="btn button-black">Get Started</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is what it currently looks like
[image: Pop out hidden example]